# Does Euro work in Hungary?

Tags: money, hungary

I am finding it hard to buy Hungarian Forint in Bangalore, India. Can I take euros to Hungary? Will those work ?

Comment: Short answer: not really, especially outside of larger tourist-oriented shops with a poor exchange rate. Your best bet is to use an ATM in Hungary if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **only universally accepted currency** in Hungary is the forint, but euros are easily exchanged (at good exchange rates) and may be accepted as is (at poor exchange rates) in larger restaurants, shops, etc.

So if you have to have cash in hand before you arrive, rupees → euros → forint is likely an OK way to go, although you will lose twice on the exchange.  However, [withdrawing forints from an ATM in Hungary will almost certainly get even better rates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26930/how-can-i-reduce-expenses-on-currency-conversions).

Comment: I think I can take some euros from here. And over there withdraw/exchange INR -> HUF at the airport ?

Comment: Withdrawing at airport ATMs is OK.  Exchange rates at the airport will likely be bad, but doesn't really matter for small sums.

Comment: What about interchange ? Are they good ?

Comment: What do you mean by "interchange"?

Comment: Its apparently an exchange counter